What is the entity that resides at a point with a radial coordinate $r$?
In his groundbreaking paper The formation of a blast wave by a very intense explosion I. Theoretical discussion, G.I.Taylor presented a number of equations, including the ones depicted below:

In relation to Eq. 3: radial velocity, $u = R^{-\frac{3} {2}}\phi _{1}$*, where $\phi _{1}$ is a function of $\eta$ ,  and $\eta = \frac {r} {R} $, and $r$ is the radial distance, my question is, when $u$ is used in his later equation (10):

what resides at the radial position $r$? What is at positioned at the radial distance $r$ that is moving at velocity $u$? In the trivial cases, it could be the centre of the explosion where $\eta =0$ so $u = 0$ and it could be the shock wave itself, in which case $\eta =1$.
In the preamble, he refers to a "particle of air" without further clarification, and I know he isn't talking about molecules.
I have read Batchelor, Landau & Lifshitz and Faber, all of whom indicate a particle is a volume of the gas, significantly larger than the MFP of the constituent molecules, but significantly smaller than the dimensions of the subject. Many authors on the subject, e.g. Rankine, Lanchester, Prandtl, Sedov  etc, use the term particle but make no attempt to present a definition and presumably leave it up to the reader to form their own view.
There seems to me to be a deep paradox in fluid dynamics, particularly in relation to gases, where the kinematic property of distance, relating to the spacing, to any degree of precision, between points, with position but zero extent, is used in conjunction with properties of pressure, density and temperature which only exist within the continuum realm with dimensions that only exist on a macroscopic scale. Taylor's Equation (10) is just such an example.
So, what precisely is the entity that resides at the point with a radial coordinate $r$?
*I may have the exponent of $R$ incorrect, the resolution of my copy of the paper is not high enough to determine precisely.

Maybe it is like a fluid parcel? I.e. small enough so derivatives for expectation values almost makes sense but large enough so we ignore details. ( at least that is how I remember them )

This refined version of your earlier question is much clearer. Indeed, whenever we talk about quantities like velocity in fluid dynamics, we mean a suitable average over a finite region. We hope that the parameters of the problem are such that this is a reasonable approximation. However, this is definitely not true in a vicinity of a shock, by definition -- a shock is a location where a naively averaged quantity changes discontinuously!

The resolution is that Taylor's equation 10 only works away from the shock. At the shock itself, none of the averaged quantities are even defined, and moreover $p/\rho^\gamma$ does not stay the same as a gas parcel passes through the shock, due to shock heating. The usual way we analyze shock waves is to set up averaged equations that hold away from the shock, and then analyze what happens across the shock itself using more general principles like boundary conditions and conservation laws.

In fluid dynamics, particularly when discussing gases, there indeed exists a conceptual challenge when we try to reconcile the microscopic and macroscopic descriptions of the fluid. The entity that resides at a point with a radial coordinate ( r ) in a fluid dynamic context is typically an infinitesimal volume element of the fluid. This volume element, although conceptually point-like, actually encompasses a multitude of molecules and must be large enough to statistically represent the properties of the fluid such as pressure, density, and temperature.
In the context of Taylor's Equation (10) and similar fluid dynamics equations, the radial coordinate ( r ) helps in setting up the mathematical framework to solve fluid dynamics problems by defining how properties change spatially. However, it's crucial to remember that each point in these equations represents an average over an infinitesimal volume, not a true mathematical point. This conceptualization helps in resolving the apparent paradox between kinematic properties (like distance) and continuum properties (like pressure and density).

The model being used here is a continuum model, in which the gas is modelled as a continuum in which properties such as pressure ($p$) and density ($\rho$) are functions of position and time. In this particular case there is an assumption of spherical symmetry, so $p$ and $\rho$ are functions of $r$ and $t$ only, and the velocity of the gas $u$ is always radial.
The physical justification of this model is that the atoms or molecules of the gas are sufficiently small that there is a scale $\delta x$ such that $p$, $\rho$ and $u$ will be approximately constant over a small volume $\delta x^3$, but where $\delta x^3$ still contains enough atoms or molecules of gas for bulk properties such as $p$, $\rho$ and $u$ to be defined for that small volume.
As pointed out in a comment, this assumption holds throughout most of the gas, but breaks down at the surface of the shockwave itself.
